# passing an array of chars to external assembly function

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

so my question is  basic but i had a hard time finding anything on the internet.
lets say i want to write a function in **C** that calls an external nasm function written in `x86_64` assembly.

I want to pass to the external function two `char*` of numbers, preform some arithmetic operations on the two and return `char*` of the result. My idea was to iterate over [rdi] and [rsi] somehow and saving the result in rax (i.e add rax, [rdi], [rsi]) but I'm having a hard time to actually do so. what would be the right way to go over each character? increasing [rsi] and [rdi]? and also- I would only need to move to rax the value of the first character right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Increase `rsi` and `rdi`, not `[rsi]` and `[rdi]` as those would increment the values pointed to.

Comment: "x85_64", :think:... you mean x86_64 ? Each compiler is allow to follow his own ABI so you need to specifier your compiler.

Comment: @Jester im lacking alot of knowledge as you can see. so lets say, i increase rsi and rdi each iteration, how could i keep the char of each result in each iteration without the having the pointer of this string not being pointed to the last character ? or will this not happen?

Comment: Jester's point is we don't even know enough about the ABI to tell whether RSI or RDI are correct. For instance if you are on Windows doing x86-64 development the registers are entirely different (and the rules associated with the calling convention are too). Linux and OS.X share a common ABI (System V ABI, but have different system calling convention). So to start, are you doing this on Linux? MacOS? Windows? Something else?

Comment: You are looking two pass two pointers. I'm curious how you intended to find the end of the array?(ie: How do you know how many elements are in the arrays)? Are you going to pass that as another parameter? Is there a special number you will look for and will stop when you find it?

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes i am using linux,and im passing also specified lengths to the function. sorry i didnt mention this...

Comment: You say you are passing an array of chars (char *) but you mention numbers.A single character holds the value 0x00 to 0xFF.Are you dealing with an array of single bytes or are you dealing with shorts, ints, longs?Might help if you showed us the _C_ (extern) prototype of the function you are calling.

Answer (score 1):

If you could post assembly/C code - it would be easier to suggest changes.

For any assembly, I would start with a C code(since I think in C :)) and then convert to assembly using a compiler and then optimize it in the assembly as needed. Assuming you need write a function which takes two strings and adds them and returns the result as int like the following:

```
int ext_asm_func(unsigned char *arg1, unsigned char *arg2, int len)
{
    int i, result = 0;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        result += arg1[i] + arg2[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is assembly (generated by gcc https://godbolt.org/g/1N6vBT):

```
ext_asm_func(unsigned char*, unsigned char*, int):
        test    edx, edx
        jle     .L4
        lea     r9d, [rdx-1]
        xor     eax, eax
        xor     edx, edx
        add     r9, 1
.L3:
        movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rdi+rdx]
        movzx   r8d, BYTE PTR [rsi+rdx]
        add     rdx, 1
        add     ecx, r8d
        add     eax, ecx
        cmp     r9, rdx
        jne     .L3
        rep ret
.L4:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Comment: Thats exactly what im trying to do. Im having a hard time to follow your assembly code though, may i ask you maybe to explain it? Thanks alot for your help!!

Comment: You could use `gcc  -Wa,-adlh -O1 -g test2.c` to get C source code block related to an assembly.